# How to use trained model in tensorflow, using CNNs to detect object with bounding box

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, object-detection-api

I have built model in tensorflow use CNNs with accuracy over 90%. It's really worked but I don't know how to use this model to detect object with bounding box which I have trained. My model include many class and once label asociated with name of class. I'd read some way about ssd, it can do that but I don't really understand how it work. My CNNs below :

```
def cnn_model_fn(features,labels,mode):
#Input layer
input_layer = tf.reshape(features["x"],[-1,28,28,1])

#Convolutional layer 1
conv1 = tf.layers.conv2d(
inputs=input_layer,
filters=32,
kernel_size=[5,5],
padding="same",
activation=tf.nn.relu)

#Pooling Layer 1
pool1 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=conv1,pool_size=[2,2],strides=2)

#Convolutional layer 2
conv2 = tf.layers.conv2d(
    inputs=pool1,
    filters=64,
    kernel_size=[5,5],
    padding="same",
    activation=tf.nn.relu)

#Pooling layer 2
pool2 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=conv2,pool_size=[2,2],strides=2)

#Debse layer
pool2_flat = tf.reshape(pool2,[-1,7*7*64])
dense = tf.layers.dense(inputs=pool2_flat,units=1024,activation=tf.nn.relu)

#Dropout
dropout = tf.layers.dropout(inputs=dense,rate=0.4,training=mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN)

#Logits layer
logits = tf.layers.dense(inputs=dropout,units=10)

predictions = {
"classes":tf.argmax(input=logits,axis=1),
"probabilities":tf.nn.softmax(logits,name="softmax_tensor")
}

if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.PREDICT:
    return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode,predictions=predictions)

#Calculate Loss
onehot_labels = tf.one_hot(indices=tf.cast(labels,tf.int32),depth=10)
loss = tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy(onehot_labels=onehot_labels,logits=logits)

if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN:
    optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001)
    train_op = optimizer.minimize(
        loss=loss,
        global_step=tf.train.get_global_step())
    return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode,loss=loss,train_op=train_op)

eval_metric_ops = {
"accuracy":tf.metrics.accuracy(labels=labels,predictions=predictions["classes"])
}

return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode,loss=loss,eval_metric_ops=eval_metric_ops)
```

And I run my app with main:

```
def main(unused_argv):
# Load training and eval data
train_data_dir = "W:/Projects/AutoDrive/Training"
test_data_dir = "W:/Projects/AutoDrive/Testing"

images,labels = load_data(train_data_dir) 
test_images,test_labels = load_data(test_data_dir)

print("Labels: {0} \nImages: {1}".format(len(set(labels)),len(images)))

for image in images[:5]:
    print("shape: {0}, min: {1}, max: {2}".format(image.shape, image.min(), image.max()))

images = [skimage.transform.resize(image,(28,28,1)) for image in images]

for image in images[:5]:
    print("shape: {0}, min: {1}, max: {2}".format(image.shape, image.min(), image.max()))

images = np.asarray(images,dtype=np.float32)
labels = np.asarray(labels,dtype=np.int32)


# Create the Estimator
TSRecognition_classifier = tf.estimator.Estimator(
model_fn=cnn_model_fn, model_dir="/tmp/TSRecognition_convnet_model")

# Set up logging for predictions
# Log the values in the "Softmax" tensor with label "probabilities"
tensors_to_log = {"probabilities": "softmax_tensor"}
logging_hook = tf.train.LoggingTensorHook(
tensors=tensors_to_log, every_n_iter=50)

# Train the model
train_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
                       x={"x": images},
                       y=labels,
                       batch_size=100,
                       num_epochs=None,
                       shuffle=True)

TSRecognition_classifier.train(
         input_fn=train_input_fn,
         steps=20000,
         hooks=[logging_hook])

# Evaluate the model and print results
eval_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
                        x={"x": test_images},
                        y=test_labels,
                        num_epochs=1,
                        shuffle=False)
eval_results = TSRecognition_classifier.evaluate(input_fn=eval_input_fn)
print(eval_results)
```

And this is full code if you want to see:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import os
import skimage.data
import skimage.transform
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.INFO)

def load_data(data_dir):
    """Load Data and return two lists"""
    directories = [d for d in os.listdir(data_dir) if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(data_dir,d))]

    list_labels = []
    list_images = []

    for d in directories:
        label_dir = os.path.join(data_dir,d)
        file_names = [os.path.join(label_dir,f) for f in os.listdir(label_dir) if f.endswith(".ppm")]
        for f in file_names:
            list_images.append(skimage.data.imread(f))
            list_labels.append(int(d))

    return list_images,list_labels

def display_images_and_labels(images,labels):
    unique_labels = set(labels)
    plt.figure(figsize=(15,15))
    i = 1
    for label in unique_labels:
        image = images[labels.index(label)]
        plt.subplot(8,8,i)
        plt.axis('off')
        plt.title("Label {0} ({1})".format(label,labels.count(label)))
        i += 1
        _ = plt.imshow(image)
        plt.show()

def cnn_model_fn(features,labels,mode):
        #Input layer
        input_layer = tf.reshape(features["x"],[-1,28,28,1])

        #Convolutional layer 1
        conv1 = tf.layers.conv2d(
            inputs=input_layer,
            filters=32,
            kernel_size=[5,5],
            padding="same",
            activation=tf.nn.relu)

        #Pooling Layer 1
        pool1 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=conv1,pool_size=[2,2],strides=2)

        #Convolutional layer 2
        conv2 = tf.layers.conv2d(
                   inputs=pool1,
                   filters=64,
                   kernel_size=[5,5],
                   padding="same",
                   activation=tf.nn.relu)

         #Pooling layer 2
         pool2 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=conv2,pool_size=[2,2],strides=2)

         #Debse layer
         pool2_flat = tf.reshape(pool2,[-1,7*7*64])
         dense = tf.layers.dense(inputs=pool2_flat,units=1024,activation=tf.nn.relu)

         #Dropout
         dropout = tf.layers.dropout(inputs=dense,rate=0.4,training=mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN)

         #Logits layer
         logits = tf.layers.dense(inputs=dropout,units=10)

         predictions = {
              "classes":tf.argmax(input=logits,axis=1),
              "probabilities":tf.nn.softmax(logits,name="softmax_tensor")
               }

         if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.PREDICT:
            return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode,predictions=predictions)

         #Calculate Loss
         onehot_labels = tf.one_hot(indices=tf.cast(labels,tf.int32),depth=10)
         loss = tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy(onehot_labels=onehot_labels,logits=logits)

         if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN:
            optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001)
            train_op = optimizer.minimize(
                         loss=loss,
                         global_step=tf.train.get_global_step())
            return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode,loss=loss,train_op=train_op)

         eval_metric_ops = {"accuracy":tf.metrics.accuracy(labels=labels,predictions=predictions["classes"])
}


          return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode,loss=loss,eval_metric_ops=eval_metric_ops)


def main(unused_argv):
    # Load training and eval data
    train_data_dir = "W:/Projects/AutoDrive/Training"
    test_data_dir = "W:/Projects/AutoDrive/Testing"

    images,labels = load_data(train_data_dir) 
    test_images,test_labels = load_data(test_data_dir)

    print("Labels: {0} \nImages: {1}".format(len(set(labels)),len(images)))

    for image in images[:5]:
        print("shape: {0}, min: {1}, max: {2}".format(image.shape, image.min(), image.max()))

    images = [skimage.transform.resize(image,(28,28,1)) for image in images]

    for image in images[:5]:
        print("shape: {0}, min: {1}, max: {2}".format(image.shape, image.min(), image.max()))

    images = np.asarray(images,dtype=np.float32)
    labels = np.asarray(labels,dtype=np.int32)


    # Create the Estimator
    TSRecognition_classifier = tf.estimator.Estimator(
    model_fn=cnn_model_fn, model_dir="/tmp/TSRecognition_convnet_model")

    # Set up logging for predictions
    # Log the values in the "Softmax" tensor with label "probabilities"
    tensors_to_log = {"probabilities": "softmax_tensor"}
   logging_hook = tf.train.LoggingTensorHook(
                   tensors=tensors_to_log, every_n_iter=50)

    # Train the model
    train_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
                       x={"x": images},
                       y=labels,
                       batch_size=100,
                       num_epochs=None,
                       shuffle=True)

    TSRecognition_classifier.train(
         input_fn=train_input_fn,
         steps=20000,
         hooks=[logging_hook])

    # Evaluate the model and print results
    eval_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
                        x={"x": test_images},
                        y=test_labels,
                        num_epochs=1,
                        shuffle=False)
    eval_results = TSRecognition_classifier.evaluate(input_fn=eval_input_fn)
    print(eval_results)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    tf.app.run()
```

Addtionally, I've seen video which I think it can help me. But they just help me train single object. Any ideas can help me ?

Answer (score 0):

There are some CNN that can output bounding boxes, and some CNN that only classify the input images. Yours is the second type. If you want bounding boxes with tensorflow, you can use the object detection API that allows you to build multi-class SSD and faster-rcnn : https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection